# .NET Remoting socket won't die, even after Process does

Tags: .net, sockets, process, release

Please consider this fairly simple scenario. I have two.NET 4.0/C# console applications. Let's call their names "Launcher" and "SocketApp."

Launcher does nothing more than launch SocketApp under a particular set of circumstances. It does so using the Process.Start() method. SocketApp runs for a while and after some period its Main() loop exits and the process dies. And the process stays dead until Launcher starts it up again. (Under no condition will multiple instances of SocketApp be launched). And so the cycle goes. This runs fine for days at a time.

But occasionally SocketApp won't start. It throws an exception when the Remoting channel tries to listen on a socket. The exception is thrown down deep in the internal Remoting code, on a Bind() call to be exact. The reason the bind call fails is because the socket somehow never got released on the PREVIOUS successful run of SocketApp. I know this is the case because if I ensure SocketApp is closed and I do a netstat -n, I can see that the port I want to Bind() to is tied up. It's in a permanent CLOSE_WAIT state. And it just stays in that CLOSE_WAIT state forever.

The only way to get Windows to release that socket is to (and this is where it gets weird) close the Launcher app. Why in the world would this be? Launcher runs in its own process and doesn't use sockets at all. It's only purpose is to launch SocketApp. So why would Launcher's closure free a socket that only SocketApp uses? Could it be because I'm not calling Dispose() on the Process object from Launcher? This glitch appears so rarely that it takes days to determine if any particular fix is effective. Anything else I should be looking at?

Dexter

Comment: I would bet a King Sized Reese's Peanut Butter Cup that the problem is that you're not calling Dispose() from the launcher as you asked, but I'm not confident enough of that to post it as an answer.  It makes the most senst to me, considering how garbage collection works.

Comment: I've added a Dispose() call. I'll know in a few days whether or not it's effective. ASIDE: I'm not too familiar with this site. What's the difference between a "comment" and an "answer"?

Comment: Comment upvotes don't get added to reputation. Comments are for side conversations regarding the question and answers. Sometimes if people don't have a definitive answer, they post it as a comment.

Comment: Also, instead of adding a Dispose() call, use a using(){} clause to do it for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is actually in the hands of the operating system to release the port at that point. The port will hang around in use for [4 minutes by default in Windows](http://www.1sttrax.net/kb/registry/TimeWait.htm). Here's a reference for [unix](http://forum.soft32.com/linux2/Parameter-change-TIME_WAIT-interval-ftopict31366.html).

Comment: Yes, a rational person would think so. I've seen reference to that 4min timeout all over the web, but unfortunately that's not what happens. It stays in CLOSE_WAIT forever... until I close the LauncherApp. :(

Comment: Sounds like you are missing your Dispose calls. Wrap the socket usage in a using statement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx